# Attempting to create a new tauri app causes permissions error

Tags: rust, command-line, permissions, tauri, yew

I am new to working with tauri, and when I run cargo create-tauri-app it runs the 'setup' and askes for app name, package manager (cargo) and UI template.  After choosing the final option, it says permission denied.  I tried running the command with sudo but then it says no such subcommand: 'create-tauri-app'.

[image: Screenshot of attempting both options]

Comment: Probably `create-tauri-app` is not installed on your sudo user. Try `sudo cargo install create-tauri-app`.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman that seemed to fix it, thanks